# How do I get smoothState.js to work with my side-drawer navigation and other jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the [materialize framework](http://materializecss.com/) and [smoothState.js](http://weblinc.github.io/jquery.smoothState.js/), and have noticed two glaring problems.

1. When I shrink down to mobile view and (And a mobile device for that matter), when clicking the hamburger icon It fires but it doesn't work as expected. e.g. clicking to different pages doesn't work.
2. SS appears to meddle with the image slider library too, suddenly my navigation disappears.
3. Smoothstate seems to work in desktop mode however I am still getting the problems with my slider for my images. And there seems to be a lag, when it fires, like it's revving up before firing.

I made a fiddle but I can't figure out how to make the separate pages link within one fiddle. Sorry. Maybe someone can show me!

As a preview, below is my css && js.

https://jsfiddle.net/718BkQns/L1rd0gLc/

css:

```
.m-scene .scene_element {
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.m-scene .scene_element--fadein {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

.m-scene.is-exiting .scene_element {
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}

/*
 * Keyframes
 */
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

js:

```
    ;(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  var $body    = $('html, body'), // Define jQuery collection 
      content  = $('#main').smoothState({
        onStart : {
          duration: 250,
          render: function () {
            content.toggleAnimationClass('is-exiting');

            // Scroll user to the top
            $body.animate({ 'scrollTop': 0 });

          }
        }
      }).data('smoothState');
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks, in advance!